# Is it possible to upload file using multipart/form-data request and ranges?

Tags: java, http, servlets, file-upload, multipartform-data

Is it possible to upload file using `multipart/form-data` request and ranges? I'm using File Upload API in Servlet 3.0. Let's say I will add the header `Range:` like:

```
-----------------------------88626153133358610029
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="someFile.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Range: 350-720

(data starts here and ends with -----------------------------88626153133358610029 )
```

Is it possible to do it on browser side? How to tell the browser to send only that part of file? The goal is to be able to resume the file upload if connection have been lost, or just to pause the upload.

I think before uploading the file, I can post `XMLHttpRequest` to find out the progress of file upload.

Comment: Not natively by HTTP (and thus also not natively by Servlet). You'd need to write a bit of logic yourself. Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830130/resume-uploads-using-http