# How to improve the performance of Multiple Image/file Upload from Client Browser to Server using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, reactjs

I have to accelerate the process of file upload coz our application has to handle large files. looking for a good technique to improve file upload process.

Comment: get a better ISP?

Comment: As the operator of the server there is absolutely nothing you can do. You are at the mercy of the upload speed of the user connected to you. If you control the client that's sending the information, look in to compressing the data first. That's about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's true that you can't change the amount of bandwidth the user has available, you're not totally helpless; there are a number of things you can do to make life easier for them:

- Obviously, give the user visible feedback on progress of each upload as well as on the combined total.
- Make sure individual uploads can be [paused](http://www.resumablejs.com) if necessary.
- In the case of failed or partial uploads, don't discard the received data; make sure there's an easy way for the user to find it and [resume the upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830130/resume-uploads-using-http) instead of starting from scratch.
- If there are multiple simultaneous uploads going on, watch the upload rate -- if they're going very slowly, indicating bandwidth constraints, consider automatically switching to sequential uploads instead (so that in case of interruption the user won't be stuck with a bunch of partial files).
- Give the user something to do while they wait.  If there's other data entry related to the uploaded files, let them do that during the upload instead of just making them stare at a progress bar.  (For example if they're uploading video, let them fill in the title and description and tagging and etc while the upload is in progress.)
- There's a whole host of UX techniques you can use to [make the upload *feel* faster](http://chrisharrison.net/projects/progressbars2/ProgressBarsHarrison.pdf) than it actually is. (A "backwards decelerating ribbed progress bar" can be perceived as 12% faster than a solid bar, for example.)